# How to change the background colour of ListView on ios

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

I'm trying to change the backgorund colour of a ListView item on ios.

for Android i have this in my index.tss and it works fine :

```
'#ListView': { 
  top:'0%', 
  left:'0%',
  height:'100%',
  width:'98%',
  zIndex:1,
  backgroundImage: "/main.png",
  backgroundColor:'#2e2f30',
  borderColor:'transparent', 
  borderWidth:0, 
  borderRadius:0, 
  separatorColor:'#2d2f2f', 
  opacity:1
```

Im using an ImageView inside each item to basically just create and display a scrollable image list.

On Android, each row displays the image perfectly full without the white border around the image like on ios.

I want to remove the white colour background around the image on each row.

Titanium SDK 8.0

Regards

Comment: Can you show us how it looks right now on ios?

Comment: on which iPhone you are trying to set the background color?
I think on iOS 7 the default background color of each list item is white. Try changing that to transparent.

Comment: How do you change the color of the rows from white to any other color? changing the color is not even working.

Comment: can you show the list template? need to see the xml

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer.

I have set the item to transparent, thanks Mr. mukesh.kumar .

Regards